# Array int convertir a array string - java

Tags: java, array, string, replace

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que es un juego similar al bingo. Todo lo realizo para que se vea en consola. Tengo un array de números generados aleatoriamente y necesito que dentro de ese array, cuando adivino un número, me reemplace el número por “XX” y lo imprima en consola. Paso a mostrar mi codigo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bucles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // JUEGO PRIMITIVA//

        // Creo el array de 9 numeros aleatorios (sin repetidos).
            int primitiva[] = new int[9];
            Random claseRandom = new Random();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                boolean repetido = false;
                int num = 10 + claseRandom.nextInt(101 - 10);
    
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (primitiva[j] == num) {
                        repetido = true;
                    }
                }
    
                if (!repetido) {
                    primitiva[i] = num;
                } else {
                    i--;
                }
            }

        // Imprimo array de 9 numeros al azar.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primitiva));

        // Jugador escoge un numero, hasta 15 veces

        int cont = 1;

        while (cont < 16) {
            
            //Convierto array int a array string
            String[] stringArray = new String[primitiva.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < primitiva.length; i++) {
                stringArray[i] = String.valueOf(primitiva[i]);
            }
            
            //Escogo un numero y lo convierto a string (para poder compararlo con el array)
            
            System.out.println("\n\nEscriba un número:");
            int numero = sc.nextInt();
            
            String num = Integer.toString(numero);
            
            //Busco numero en el array y reemplazo por "XX" si es que lo encuentra.
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {          
                if (stringArray[j] == num) {
                    stringArray[j] = "XX";
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
            }

            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
            cont++;
        }
    }

}
```

En esta ultima parte donde donde hago el if (stringArray[j] == num) dentro del for, me da falso. O sea, el numero(convertido a string del array) y el numero escrito al azar(tambien convertido a string) no los reconoce como iguales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más sencilla sería ir copiándolo.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[intArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i<intArray; i++){
   stringArray[i] = String.valueOf(intArray[i]);
}
```

Otra posible solución sería empezar ya con el Array de Strings y cuando introduzcan un número comparar las cadenas con el método equals.

Comment: Tu código dará el siguiente error: *error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String*. Debes usar algún método para convertir el int en String, por ejemplo, `String.valueOf(intArray[i]);`

Comment: Gracias! Voy a probar.
No puedo empezar con un array de strings porque previamente tengo una funcion para que me genere un array de numeros aleatorios

Comment: Ahi actualice el codigo y la pregunta a ver si me pueden ayudar, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en igualar string cunado recorria el array para reemplazarlo con "XX", cuando se trata de strings se pone equals:

stringArray[j].equals(num) y ahi si me da "true".